# Payment Handlers In Google Chrome

Tags: google, chrome, payment

Are there any privacy/security risks associated with using payment handlers in Google Chrome?

Somehow, the idea of having my financial information stored in a browser makes me feel uncomfortable. I almost always use PayPal whenever I decide to shop on non-Amazon websites to avoid giving my financial information directly to the website, so should I disable this?

To be clear, the setting I'm asking about can be found in Google Chrome under Settings > Advanced > Content settings > Payment Handlers.

Comment: This is now possibly under: `chrome://settings/payments?search=payment`

Answer (score 0):

This varies from service to service as certain payment handlers provide better security than others, also how the browser and the site encrypt your payment information. Generally though, all payment information will be stored and handled locally on your browser, meaning that the browser can view and access your financial credentials. Because of this, your information could be susceptible to malware and spyware attacks that can see your details compromised from the browser where they are stored. It is strongly suggested that you continue using more secure payment services like PayPal, and if you need to pay using payment handlers make sure to delete the information after the transaction is completed.